# Are XSS bugs still dangerous if the script is injected into a private page?

Tags: php, security, xss

Let's say there's an XSS bug on a site. There's a simple address form, and after submitting the form, the entered information is being reflected **within the same page** without being escaped. The entered information is being handled with a POST request, so you can't define variables through URL.
**So basically, the script is being injected into a private page that is only visible to the user that has sent the malicious request.**

### Can this bug be abused somehow? Could this be a threat for other users?

Here's an example code:

```
<form method="POST" >

    <input type="text" name="addressline1" />
    <input type="text" name="addressline2" />

    <button>Submit</button>

</form>

<?php 

    if(isset($_POST["addressline1"]) && isset($_POST["addressline2"])){
        $adress = $_POST["addressline1"]."<br />".$_POST["addressline2"];
        echo "<h1>YOUR ADDRESS IS: <br />".$adress."</h1>";

    }

?>
```

I am new to this security stuff and I was not able to think a scenario where this bug could be a threat to other users. I'd be really glad if guys could help me out. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The attacker just needs to host a malicious page on a server they control which includes a `<form method="POST">` and some JavaScript to submit it as soon as the page loads.